# SharePoint 2013 On-Premise Server Side Validation For Parent Child Form

Tags: sharepoint-server

Using SharePoint 2013 On-Premise, I am writing an app using a Content Editor Web Part, using a JS Framework, either jQuery or Angular. Hopefully in future to be transferred to the SPFx when it comes on-premise.

I am looking to write a simple form, which will consist of a parent row for employees details and then multiple children rows, for list item. I anticipate storing data in two lists, one with the parent row and another list for each list item, linked with a lookup ID in the line item row.

How I can complete the server side validation of the item in the parent list, and server side validation of the items in the children list, and not commit all records until I know both list saves will be successful? Is it a case of saving the parent list as a draft item and then publish it when all items in the children list have been saved successfully?

I am thinking of using Server Side Event Receivers to keep it simple as opposed to using Remote Event Recievers or Web API. Whilst I appreciate Microsoft guidance on the matters of keeping all solutions from the server, this is only a small app so dont want to overkill.